# Table vertices - clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

How can I get a 2-column-table with the cluster corresponding to each vertex? I already have clustered my data and I can see what is contained in ech cluster; I'm interested in seeing the combination so that I can later match these data with new data. I'm using igraph for the cluster analysis.

I'd like to have something like this (just an example, not my real data):

```
Data    Cluster
Jane    1
Max     1
Sally   2
Robert  3
Ginny   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clustering objects that `igraph` returns contain a member called `membership` - this is a vector where the i-th element is the cluster identifier for the i-th node. So, you can simply do this:

```
> cl <- some.clustering.method.from.igraph(graph)
> n <- vcount(graph)
> cbind(vertices=1:n, clusters=cl$membership)
```

Or, if your graph has names associated to the vertices, then:

```
> cbind(vertices=V(graph)$name, clusters=cl$membership)
```